# mvn install DskipTests error 'mv: cannot remove apache-maven-3.2.5 No such file or directory'

Tags: hadoop

I got the issue by using following command.

```
cd metron-deployment/packaging/docker/rpm-docker
  mvn clean install -DskipTests -PHDP-2.5.0.0 . .


[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (docker-build) @ metron-rpm ---
Sending build context to Docker daemon 842.5 MB
Step 1/13 : FROM centos:centos6
 ---> d0957ffdf8a2
Step 2/13 : RUN yum install -y tar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bdc0c1cfe815
Step 3/13 : RUN yum install -y wget
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a39bcec938e0
Step 4/13 : RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 67857c9ce3c1
Step 5/13 : WORKDIR /usr/src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> afbc7a591163
Step 6/13 : RUN wget http://apache.cs.utah.edu/maven/maven-3/3.2.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ea0b2ddde0d
Step 7/13 : RUN tar xzvf apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eab37a7e2958
Step 8/13 : RUN mv apache-maven-3.2.5 /opt/maven
 ---> Running in ee91532580b7

mv: cannot remove `apache-maven-3.2.5/LICENSE': No such file or directory
mv: cannot remove `apache-maven-3.2.5/NOTICE': No such file or directory
mv: cannot remove `apache-maven-3.2.5/README.txt': No such file or directory
mv: cannot remove `apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/m2.conf': No such file or directory
```

Any idea please help

Thanks

I have updated below file. but still same error

```
vi /etc/profile

export M2_HOME=/opt/maven

export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

export PATH=$M2:$PATH

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"

 source /etc/profile
```

Comment: Is the maven artifact located under /usr/src?

Comment: that directory contains only following shown files. if you mean m./repository of maven, it does not exist in this folder

ls -lrt /usr/src

drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  6 Apr 10  2018 debug
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 67 Jun 26 09:58 kernels


ls -lrt  /usr/src/kernels/
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Jun 26 07:47 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Jun 26 09:58 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64